# Executing PHP script from command-line

Tags: command-line, script, php

It has been a while since I did any scripting with php. Now that I'm back at it, I find I'm missing something simple. Currently, the only way I am able to run my scripts is with the php command in front of them:

```
> php script.php
```

What do I need to do to enable running them directly? For reference, I am on kubuntu 10.0.4, and the php executable is located in `/usr/bin/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is most often interpreted (it can be compiled but that's often more work than it's worth). So the way your running PHP is the best and most straight forward way to run PHP via commandline. If you really dislike including `php` every time your can include `#!/usr/bin/php` at the beginning of the file and then run them directly. Before you can run them make sure to set the execute flag `> chmod +x helloworld.php`.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

`> helloworld.php`

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Would you say the same thing is true for python scripts? (e.g. that they are best run by `> python script.py` )

Comment: Probably the easiest way to find out the answer is to try it. Post up your findings.

Comment: I used to do this when all I knew was PHP. Then I learned Perl. Don't forget to `chmod +x` the PHP file before trying to run it as a command.

Comment: @amphetamachine good catch

Comment: @SoftwareElves I wasn't asking if the same command would make python scripts executable. I was asking if the same best practice applied. That is, if it better to run python scripts via `> pythong script.py` than to add a similar line and run them as executable. I don't see how "testing to find out" applies when weighing on which option is better.

Comment: @JGB1486 I don't know if either of them are "best practice". If I had to guess it would think that calling the .php via the interpreter would be the "best", since it's more portable (I would assume that same applies for python). The only reason to prepend the `#!...` stuff to be beginning of the file is if you need to call as a normal shell script (ie including it in /usr/local/bin).